# GPL Ghostscript 9.10: **** Could not open temporary file '' **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting

Tags: java, batch-file, ghostscript

I am running the batch file for compressing pdf through GhostScript. I am able to pass parameters and run the batch file from java. But, i get the following error,

GPL Ghostscript 9.10: **** Could not open temporary file ''
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

But this doesn't occur when i separately the batch file.

```
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -r300 -sCompression=lzw -sOutputFile=%1 
"C:/source.pdf"
```

Thanks, 
Pavithra M

Comment: Well this is nothing related to java, the problem is your batch file

Comment: Yes. you are correct. The batch files runs fine, when i run it as standalone.But I am not able to run from java only.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I fixed the issue. Actually I was running as follows,  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start D:\\worspace\\Test\\src\\com\\test\\pdfCompressor\\compressPDFFiles.bat trial.pdf  converted.pdf");. Here i passed two parameters in the exec command itself. Before that i was trying to pass it as new String{"trial.pdf","convertedpdf"} in the exec method.